# How do I insert the bar for "evaluated at" in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to make an integral by parts step by step, so I'm trying to write the first term: `u*v` `(evaluated between A and B)` but I have no idea of how to insert the usual bar to indicate the evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that SymPy printers have is `Subs`, the inert form of substitution of one expression for another. For example

```
>>> u, v = x, sin(x)
>>> pprint(Subs(u*v, x, pi) - Subs(u*v, x, 0))
- (x⋅sin(x))│    + (x⋅sin(x))│   
            │x=0             │x=π
```

Or, in LaTeX terms,

```
>>> latex(Subs(u*v, x, pi) - Subs(u*v, x, 0))
'- \\left. x \\sin{\\left (x \\right )} \\right|_{\\substack{ x=0 }} + \\left. x \\sin{\\left (x \\right )} \\right|_{\\substack{ x=\\pi }}'
```

There is no logic for printing the bar with x = b on top and x = a at the bottom, because there is no class like Subs but with two substitutions for x.

---

To actually evaluate (not to print) such a thing, one can use

```
>>> (u*v).subs(x, pi) - (u*v).subs(x, 0)
0
```

Or, for tricky improper integrals where a limit has to be taken,

```
>>> (u*v)._eval_interval(x, S(0), pi)
0
```

The internal method `_eval_interval` takes limits instead of direct evaluation when needed.